# Call html modal form in grid link button

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am trying to call a html modal form on grid linkbutton but unable to do so..
Normally the html modal form is called like this

```
<a href="#fModal" role="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal">Modal form</a>
```

modal form code :-

```
<div class="modal fade" id="fModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>                        
                    <h4>Modal form</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body modal-body-np">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="block-fluid">
                            <div class="row-form clearfix">
                                <div class="col-md-3">First name:</div>
                                <div class="col-md-9"><input type="text" value=""/></div>
                            </div>            
                            <div class="row-form clearfix">
                                <div class="col-md-3">Last name:</div>
                                <div class="col-md-9"><input type="text" value=""/></div>                    
                            </div>                                    
                            <div class="row-form clearfix">
                                <div class="col-md-3">About:</div>
                                <div class="col-md-9"><textarea></textarea></div>
                            </div>                                                
                        </div>                
                        <div class="dr"><span></span></div>
                        <div class="block">                
                            <p>Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>   
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Save updates</button> 
                    <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>            
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Please suggest me how to do this as I want to put it in the grid do show the model form in the edit mode with some data fetched from the database based on the CommandArgument.

Comment: what exactly isn't working?

Comment: you can set div with runat="server" and add css class i.e. "fade" on link button click event.

Answer (score 0):

Considering Bootstrap v2.3+ you should use `data-target="#fModal"` instead of `href="#fModal"` Like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" role="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#fModal">Modal form</a>
```